# API Call In Google Sheets Google Apps Script Returning Code 500

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, http-status-code-500

I am trying to call cutt.ly's api for shortening urls. When pasting the cal into safari I get the desired response; however, when I make the call using URLFetch in my Google Apps Script Project (making for a Google Sheets Add On) I only get a code of 500.

I have tried the following url in Safari and it has returned the desired information: https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=[APIKEY]&short=https://www.ThisIsMyReallyLongLink.com&name=MyTestLinkThatIsUnused

However, if I make the call in Google Apps Script like so, I only get code 500: UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=[APIKEY]&short=https://www.ThisIsMyReallyLongLink.com&name=MyTestLinkThatIsUnused");

The specific error is:

> "Exception: Request failed for https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=[APIKEY]&short=https://www.ThisIsMyReallyLongLink.com&name=MyTestLinkThatIsUnused returned code 500"

Documentation for the cutt.ly API is located here https://cutt.ly/cuttly-api

Does anyone have any thoughts on why I am only getting this error in Google Apps Script and how to potentially resolve. If possible I want to avoid doing something like this UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {"muteHttpExceptions": true}) to make sure that I catch all exceptions and handle properly.

```
function test(){ 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=[APIKEY]&short=https://…); 
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your code and share your Spreadsheet.

Comment: This is not a bounded script, so there isn't a spreadsheet to share. As far as code goes, most of the function is provided above. I am currently just trying to get this working before building out the full function, so currently it is just something like this: function test(){ var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=[APIKEY]&short=https://www.ThisIsMyReallyLongLink.com&name=MyTestLinkThatIsUnused"); Logger.log(response);}

Comment: 1.Try `encodeURIComponent(queryString)` the part after `?...`. 2. explicitly use `https://cutt.ly....`. 3. Add `Accept: '*/*'` header to options

Comment: Did you ever get this to work, and if so do you have a script to share?